# Laravel: Displaying Multiple powerpoint slides in laravel project

Tags: laravel

What is the easiest way of uploading, viewing and downloading powerpoint and PDF in laravel project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found some discussion on Laravel.io and Laracast that in some sense answers the question. Follow these links

1. [Laravel.io](https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/10-02-2014-how-to-upload-files-specifically-pdf?page=1)
2. [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/pdfs-and-laravel?page=1)